# Expression cannot be handled by pattern type

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a switch statement to check against two types so I can count intersection points.

The code looks like this:

```
    public static int Intersects(this IGeometry object1, in IGeometry object2)
    {
        switch (object1, object2)
        {
            case Arc a1, Arc a2:
                    //get arc intersection count
                    break;

            default: return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

However I get the error:

```
An expression of type '(IGeometry object1, IGeometry object2)' cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'Arc'
```

Not sure why this is not possible because my Arc inherits it. My inheritance setup looks like this:

```
public struct Arc : ICurve
```

and

```
public interface ICurve : IGeometry
```

with

```
public interface IGeometry {}
```

How do I fix this error ? Not sure what I am getting wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The pattern should be `(Arc a1, Arc a2)` as in a value tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing paranthesis:

```
public static int Intersects(this IGeometry object1, in IGeometry object2)
{
    switch (object1, object2)
    {
        case (Arc a1, Arc a2):
            //get arc intersection count
            break;

        default: return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You switch on a tuple, so the pattern has to be a tuple as well.

Comment: I tried this, my editor says the brackets are redundant and the error persists anyway?

Comment: See here: https://imgur.com/cTB3Cgi ohh i didn't see the comma!

Comment: Ok it works now i misread the answer ! :)

Comment: There is an "and" in the screenshot instead of the comma.

Comment: Yeah it works now will tick your answer once the timer lets me! Thanks!